# browser does not render the html file after redirect in express.js

Tags: node.js, express, google-chrome, firefox

```
const express = require('express');
const auth = express.Router();


auth.get('/login', async (req, res) => {

    res.render('login')

})

auth.get('/register', async (req, res) => {

    res.render('register')

})

auth.post('/logout', async (req, res) => {
    res.clearCookie("token")
    res.redirect("/auth/login")

});

module.exports = auth
```

sending a request to the logout endpoint will result in cookie called token getting deleted.
. the response of the post request to /logout api has location header pointed to auth/login.in the network tab i can see the status code 200 of a get request to auth/login too . the source code of the page will change to the auth/login html content but the new page does not get rendered .
the login endpoint renders a login.ejs file .

here is the logout button event listener function too :

```
        async function logout() {
            fetch('/auth/logout', {
                method: 'POST',
                credentials: 'include' // This will include the cookie in the request
            })
                .then(response => {
                    console.log(`Response status: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
                    if (response.ok) {
                        console.log("everything was ok")
                    } else {
                        console.error('Logout failed');
                    }
                })
                .catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
        }
```

deleted the cache and no change . same conclusion on chrome and firefox . no error happens on the process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fetch returns a promise that is fulfilled once the response is available so it does not operate (redirect the browser) in same way as you assume a regular form submission works.

When you return a `res.redirect` using express your front-end JavaScript has no idea you want to change the page in the browser. Fetch will follow the redirect transparently and make another call to the url you specified in the `res.redirect` but if that url returns HTML then it won't suddenly be rendered in your browser.

Fortunately the promise that is returned from the fetch request resolves to the Response object which has both `redirected` and `url` properties.

You can check if the `redirected` property is `true` and if so use the `url` property to redirect your browser to your intended destination.

Below I have added a really simple example into your fetch to redirect but please read more about [fetch](https://javascript.info/fetch) and the [Fetch API](https://javascript.info/fetch-api) to really understand what's going on:

```js
fetch('/auth/logout', {
   method: 'POST',
   credentials: 'include', // This will include the cookie in the request
}).then(response => {
   console.log(`Response status: ${response.status} ${response.statusText}`);
   if (response.ok) {
       console.log("everything was ok")
       if(response.redirected){ //< Add this
           location.assign(response.url); //< Add this
       }
   } else {
       console.error('Logout failed');
   }
}).catch(error => console.error('Error:', error));
```

Comment: thanks  buddy . is there a way that i can redirect the page without adding the redirection logic to the client side ? i assume that the browsers can handle redirection without the need of javascript ? i always thought that a location header in an http response will be handled by the browser internals.

Comment: i have added a form with action aut/logout and method post . 
and added a submit button to it .clicking results in logging out . so i guess that's the other way of logging out without needing to handle the redirection with js

Comment: @mehdi yes the form with a method and action is the standard way to submit a form and the browser will be redirected as part of the request/response cycle. Most JS frameworks use fetch/axios to deal with form submissions but for things like login/sign up etc I always use the standard way. Now you know both approaches.